# Glossaries won't print

Tags: pdftex, glossaries

I'm currently unable to get Glossaries to work.

The documents builds fine. No errors whatsoever. But it's not printing the glossary even tho it creates a hyperref at the \glo{computer} which leads to the very first page of the document (invalid hyperref)

Here's a minmal working example:

```
    \documentclass[
 fontsize=11pt,
 a4paper,
 pdflatex
 ]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, graphicx, wrapfig, lmodern, fancyhdr, microtype}
\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}


\usepackage[xindy,
            toc,
            section,
            acronym]{glossaries}

\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbolverzeichnis}
\newacronym{cd}{CD}{compact disk}

\newglossaryentry{computer}
{
  name=computer,
  description={is a programmable machine that receives input,
               stores and manipulates data, and provides
               output in a useful format}
}


\makeglossaries 

%Damit ich 1.5 Zeilenabstände habe
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

%Der Seitenrand
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,
            right=5.5cm,
            top=2.5cm,
            bottom=2.5cm]
            {geometry}

\begin{document}

\section{Some Chapter}

You can install \gls{computer}-software using a \gls{cd}


\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

It contains all the packages I'm using even when they're not needed in the MWE (In case that some of them are incompatible)

[image: === Image ===]

Also: I'm currently using no .glo file. Is there any external program like [JabRef](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/) where I can edit my glossary the way I do it with BibTeX?

I hope you guys can help me. I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't mention `makeindex` in your question, are you running the makeindex command?
From the manual:

> Run makeindex with the .glo file as the input file and the .ist file
>   as the style so that it creates an output file with the extension
>   .gls. If you have access to a terminal or a command prompt (for
>   example, the MSDOS command prompt for Windows users or the bash
>   console for Unix-like users) then you need to run the command:
>   makeindex -s myDoc.ist -o myDoc.gls myDoc.glo

For a **quick, easy solution**, change `\makeglossaries` to `\makenoidxglossaries` and `\printglossaries`to `\printnoidxglossaries`.

This is a bit slower than the usual commands without `noidx`, but it's no problem unless you have a huge glossary.

Comment: It's working! whohoo! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Great `:)`
I've had my fair share of glossary problems as well, still don't quite understand how it works..

Comment: Do you know any sort of program I can edit .glo files with? Because it would be pretty spamming when i would put all this into my tex file preamble. Just like what JabRef does with .bib files

Comment: I don't know of anyone, sorry. I usually put all my entries in a .tex file which I then `\input{}` (this way I don't need to see it in the preamble at least)

Comment: How exactly do you embed them? This is how I do it currently: [glossary.tex](http://pastebin.com/hTPHfyZ0) and [my main tex file](http://pastebin.com/fMQ8SvnZ). It's currently not working because of this error: *"! File ended while scanning use of \newglossaryentry."* even tho it worked perfectly fine while I had a single \newglossaryentry in it. Now it just doesnt work, no matter the amount of \newglossaryentry

Comment: The reason for that error is due to your entries `\newglossaryentry{System}` and `\newglossaryentry{Betriebssystem}` not having a `}` after the `description={...`. Apart from this, you have the exact same file structure as me.

Comment: Look at me stackexchange! I am a moron! Thanks for pointing this out. Really stupid mistake on my side

Comment: It happens to everyone `:P` no problem!

Comment: is there any way I can use Synoyms? For example I'm using the word *Malware* quite often in my current Work. But I also use the german word *Schadsoftware* at the very beginning, where I haven't explained the word *Malware*. Both mean the very same thing. Can i somehow set, that they use the same glossary entry or should i create a entry for schadsoftware and then tell "Look at \gls{Malware}"

Comment: I'm not sure how it can be done (post a new question about it), but I'm thinking that it might not be a good idea to link schadsoftware to malware, that would at least confuse me. I would click on the link and expect to see an entry for schadsoftware. German isn't my first language though, maybe it's crystal clear that schadsoftware is a synonym to malware for a German speaking reader.

Comment: It's just a measly project for my IT class. My Teacher knows exactly what Schadsoftware is. But i still got some time to spare so i experiment a bit with the possebilities of LaTeX in the hope to refine my current work

Comment: Hi, I'm new to this glossary. In every other guide, they use the "normal" commands, and they print nothing in my pdf. This `noidx` version does. Why?