# Glossary does not print in tex document

Tags: glossaries

I have used the basic commands of the package [`glossaries`](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Glossaries) but the glossary itself does not print when using the command `\printglossaries`.

Using the latex code found in the link above, I cannot print the glossary. My latex installation could have not had a package installed, but after verification, they are all installed. Does anyone have an idea of what is wrong here?

```
\documentclass{report} 

\usepackage[style=authoryear,citestyle=authoryear,natbib=true,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
    name=latex, 
    description={Is a markup language specially suited for scientific documents.}
}

\begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    
    \tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1}
        
\section{Text}

Lorem ipsum \gls{latex}.

\section{Glossary}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Comment: Remark: There is a good **beginner's guide** from the package author, see http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossariesbegin.pdf (or https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries).

Comment: The glossary will not print without you using `\gls{latex}` in your main text, you are not currently using any `\gls` or similar commands so your glossary is empty. Can you confirm if in your main document you are using `\gls{}` between `\begin{document}` and `\printglossaries`? Adding `\gls{latex}` to your code printed the glossary for me.

Comment: Thank you for the reference Manuel, I will follow it closely. Thanks to have remarked the missing part @JamesT. Unfortunately, it seems that it is not the source of the problem here.

Comment: Is your `main.tex` file in the root directory? Apparently Overleaf support said that [glossaries are only printed if your main file is in the root directory](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/542163/273733), not subdirectories. What is your folder structure?

Comment: Thank you @JamesT. My file was indeed in the root directory, but I have made some experiments on where the file is located, and it does not change the problem. I don't know where this issue could come from.

Comment: If I were you I would contact Overleaf support and ask them why your glossary is not appearing, unfortunately your code compiles and prints the glossary on my local system so it is definitely something only Overleaf support would be able to help with!

Comment: Thank you very much @JamesT, at least we know it is a software issue.

Comment: No problem, if they do have a solution to your issue, could you please post it as answer and then accept it when you can please? Just helps keep the site clean! :)

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue?

Comment: This may be a solution for some people:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249693/162165 In short, there are some manual commands that need to be run when you want indexing. If you don't want/need the indexing, you can replace ```\makeglossaries``` with ```\makenoidxglossaries```. Likewise for the print commands.